Interpreter error occurs when using pyspark in Zeppelin
%spark.pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col


sc = SparkSession.builder\
        .master("yarn")\
        .appName("Test")\
        .getOrCreate()

df = sc.read.csv("hdfs:///test/KC_KOBIS_BOX_OFFIC_MOVIE_INFO_202105.csv", header=True)
df.select(col("MOVIE_NM"), col("MNG_NM"), col("IMPORT_CMPNY_NM"), col("GRAD_NM")).show()


org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Interpreter process is not running
Interpreter download command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_yarn_cluster.properties -Dzeppelin.log.file=/usr/local/zeppelin/logs/zeppelin-interpreter-spark-shared_process--dn5.log -cp '':/usr/local/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/*:::/usr/local/zeppelin/interpreter/zeppelin-interpreter-shaded-0.11.1.jar:/usr/local/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/spark-interpreter-0.11.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterDownloader 172.30.1.53 32799 spark /usr/local/zeppelin/local-repo/spark

An error like this occurs and pyspark does not run.
How can I solve this problem?
The versions are as follows.

spark 3.4.0
zeppelin 0.11.1
java 1.8.0_362
scala 2.12.17
python 3.10.6

thank you.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried modifying the interpreter settings in the zeppelin web environment, but it didn't work. I have tried many other things, but I am having difficulty solving the problem due to my lack of skills.
